# Can a defendant in a child pornography case get access to the actual material as evidence in California?

Tags: california, evidence, pornography, discovery

I am engaged in a semi-civil discussion regarding a recent case about a person in California who is accused of being in possession of child pornography. The person on the other side is of the opinion that, while it's a terrible thing to give the accused access to alleged illegal material, it is better that it be possible than the state being allowed to deny evidence to the defense.

They cite a case in Washington wherein a man who already admitted that he had molested children, and due to a combination of what I consider to be bad judgement by the state's supreme court, and a legal loophole dealing with the defendant representing themselves, was permitted to view the recordings he had made of the act while in jail and awaiting trial. Under strict observation rules of course.

My argument is that not all actual physical evidence is accessible to the defendant, or even the defense team. In many cases facsimiles such as video or photos of the evidence would suffice. As would test results and the findings of experts. In a case like this however, the evidence itself is already video or photos, and handing it over would be akin to handing over a murder weapon, or drugs.

Morality of this scenario aside, is it possible in the state of California, following the law as written regarding access to evidence for the defense, or based upon prior decisions of the state's court system, for the actual defendant in a child pornography case to have access to the actual imagery/video declared as evidence in the case? I say "actual defendant" because I want to distinguish between the defense attorney being granted access, and the defendant themselves.

Comment: "*handing it over would be akin to handing over a murder weapon, or drugs*" But why are murder weapons or drugs not handed over? Is it because the accused may use it to further commit crimes? Or because they are physical objects that are inherently unique and must be safekept against the accused who has an interest to see it disappear?

Comment: I recall hearing a barrister in the UK describe a case where the "indecent images" turned out to be the accused's grandchildren playing naked in the garden. However because of limits on letting people see the material neither defence nor prosecution had actually seen the pictures until the defence had insisted just before the trial, at which point the charges were dropped.

Comment: The problem is that in this situation looking at the evidence would normally be a crime. Tricky in every way. Even looking at photos of the evidence is bad. Unlike looking at a murder weapon or looking at photos of a murder weapon.

Comment: It seems obvious that we should not just take the state's word for it (1) that the material is pornographic, (2) that the subjects are children, and (3) that the defendant is associated with the material.  If the state does not share the material with the defense, then are we not just taking the state's word for it?  Also the intent of the CP statutes is to discourage the abuse of children.  In theory, CP creates a demand for abuse.  Sharing CP with defendants clearly does not create a demand for abuse.